# ASP.NET C# Gridview with dropdown lists per row leads to slow processing page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatables

I have a Gridview where tens or hundreds of rows can be populated from a database. This is all good and well, however the first column of each row contains a dropdown list that can load hundreds of options. The user can select one of the options (search the dropdown list) and then save the selection (all the edited rows on the page).

All works good and well however it creates a VERY slow and heavy page (as each row has this dropdown list with hundreds of options).

I cannot deploy paging and limit the number of rows to 10 for example as the users like that Datatables is used and they can search for their specific row using the search option that Datatables provides (all the data loaded into page) rather than some bespoke slow search that will only search the loaded page of data for example.

I have been wrecking my head for days now to find a solution that would suit this need, the functionality of Datatables, the dropdown for each row to allow the user to select while not restricting the number of rows loaded for the user experience.

This all with the ability for the page to load in a decent amount of time and be user friendly. Sounds like a catch 22 and am open to any suggestions.

Is there any way for example to have one javascript object with all the dropdown options and then reference it (duplicate it) for each row without actually loading the dropdown for each row on Databound?

Much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is you are making a database call for each dropdownlist? Probably don't do that. And disable ViewState.

Comment: Hi, no I have loaded the datasource once in page_load and then assigned it to each row on databound.